# nginx server-side caching of local static assets

Tags: nginx, caching

I'm trying to cache local static assets using NGINX. However, the assets aren't being cached by NGINX. The assets are served correctly, but are not written to the cache directory. Moreover, the server-side-cache-related headers are not being set.

Below is my NGINX configuration:

```
proxy_cache_path /mnt/ramdisk levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:10m;

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;

        ssl_certificate <snip>;
        ssl_certificate_key <snip>;

        location /public/ {
                autoindex on;
                root <snip>;

                # browser cache
                expires 2d;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";

                # server-side caching
                add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
                proxy_ignore_headers "Set-Cookie";
                proxy_cache my_cache;
                proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
                proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
        }
}
```

When requesting assets at this path, I'm seeing these headers:

`$ curl -I https://<my-domain>/public/img/lightbulb-lg.optimized.jpeg`

```
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx/1.10.3
date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 19:42:09 GMT
content-type: image/jpeg
content-length: 254851
last-modified: Fri, 28 Sep 2018 17:36:17 GMT
etag: "5bae6691-3e383"
expires: Thu, 04 Oct 2018 19:42:09 GMT
cache-control: max-age=172800
cache-control: public
accept-ranges: bytes
```

This correctly corresponds to the `expires` and `add_header` directives, but note the absence of the `X-Proxy-Cache` header.

Furthermore, the directory `/mnt/ramdisk` is empty. Its permissions are set to `drwxrwxrwt 2 www-data root 40 Oct  2 19:36 ramdisk` and I verified that I could write to this directory.

What's going on?

Comment: Can you give additional information about the server setup? What about Nginx logs? Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: Nothing in NGINX error logs. NGINX access log reporting access to the resource specified in CURL request. Not sure if SE linux is enabled. Is that relevant?

Comment: not sure if relevant but always a source of trouble when not using default locations. By the way, have you seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36646131/7654691)

Comment: Yes and I tried everything there including the `proxy_buffering` option.

Comment: In order to use proxy caching you need to be proxying the requests to an upstream server. The idea of caching is to store a local copy of a remote resource on your server so you can serve requests without requesting it from the remote host each time. Local static files are already cached on your machine, why do you want another copy of them?