# Nginx cache: How to Ignore ‘no-cache’ but honor ‘max-age‘ like it was ‘public’?

Tags: nginx, caching, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache-control

I want to send to browsers `Cache-Control: no-cache,max-age=120;` so they have to revalidate to use a cached copy, but that makes *Nginx* to in practice not cache anything, or at least always `MISS`.

And I cannot use `proxy_ignore_headers “Cache-Control”;` because I have to honor `max-age`, and `max-age` is controlled by the upstream server, every type of page has a different one and might change over time, so it has to be controlled by the main server.

How should the configuration be to get this?

PD: Or a way to make Nginx honor some custom X-Cache-Control header, and use separate headers to control cache for proxies and browsers.

PD2: I made this, apparently it works, but I was hoping for a more "official" way:

```
proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
proxy_hide_header maxage;
add_header Cache-Control "no-cache,max-age=$upstream_http_maxage";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `proxy_hide_header` you should use [`proxy_ignore_headers`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_ignore_headers)

Update:

and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9232739/279564 , you must use both.